# Laravel Database structure 'apply'

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

So I have a weird question.
I'm making an application in Laravel and Angular. I'm using Eloquent models.
Right now I have 2 tables, 1 users table (with the users info), and 1 events table (with the name, date, ... of an event).

These 2 are binded by a oneToMany relation (Every event belongs to an user). But now I would like people to sign up for that event. ( a switch in the front end, so they can apply for the event).

So, many users will have many events.
The catch is also, the owner of the event can manually set an maximum # users. (This is an tinyINt in my event table).

So now my question. How can I pull this off?

Options I have thought off:
1. I make a pivot table
-> Is this possible? Because the User and the event are already binded by a one to many realtion? So how can I bind them with a many to many relation again?
2. Every time a user signs op, I add his ID to an array in the events table.
-> Is this possible? I could then be able to set the maximum # users by checking the length of the array?

Thank you friends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a pivot table is the correct approach here. The fact that the two tables are already bound by a different relation should not deter you.

```php
class Events extends Eloquent
{
    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class);
    }

    public function subscribers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\User::class, 'event_user');
    }

    public function canAddSubscriber()
    {
        if ( ! $this->max_users) return true;

        return $this->max_users < $this->subscribers()->count();
    }
}
```

As you can see, you can use the relationship to determine if a subscriber can still be added.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask one more thing? Should I handle the request to add Subscribers in a different Controller? Or in my eventscontroller? Thank you so much for getting me this far!

Comment: Yeah. You can do it in your events controller.